# working videochat with a macam compatible webcam on macosx?

Tags: mac, video-chat

I have a google xmpp accoutn that I'd like to use for videochat. Given a working webcam, using macam, there is apparently no way to get a decent videochat system on mac. Neither skype nor ichat recognize the macam-fired webcam.

I tried adium (has no videochat plugin), xmeeting and jitsi (don't see the cam). Has anybody seen a working videochat that's not using iSight or not UVC-compliant?

thanks